# After Boolean union operation - correcting imperfections in joined mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, sculpting

I have joined this hand with the main body with a Boolean Union modifier.  However, the union has produced some mesh imperfection along the joined lines as you can see in the second photo.
[image]
[image]

The joined line in between the mesh seems to be quite fuzzy and the only way I can find to partially correct it is with a creese and smooth brush in sculpting mode.   The result is never totally smooth.

Is there a better way to do it?

Here is a pics of the mesh as requested.

[image]

Comment: Could you post image with wireframe visible?

Comment: Mesh pic posted.

Answer (score 1):

Shading artifacts is a common problem using the Boolean workflow. Using the bevel modifier with a very small width can help mitigate the problem. After that, consider marking any edges surrounding flat surfaces as sharp.

Finally, tab into *Edit Mode* and look for any double vertices or incorrectly shaded n-gons and fix these issues manually. Double vertices can be merged together (try selecting one, then pressing <kbd>G</kbd> twice to slide it along the edge into another vertex and *Merge by Distance* <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>).

Incorrectly shaded n-gons can be broken up, and you can add supporting edges for the merge point in the local geometry.